# How does Finn sit in the gunner seat with gravity affecting him

Tags: star-wars, physics, millennium-falcon, artificial-gravity

I'm thinking that if Finn is sitting in the Millenium Falcon and then runs to the lower turret, then as he sits in the chair for the lower turret, he is literally facing down.  This means gravity from Jakku is pulling him forward.  He certainly doesn't seem like he's being affected by Jakku's Gravity.  So how is this possible?

Comment: The magical inertial dampeners and artificial gravity used in SW ships?

Comment: [Tango's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7684/5184) directly addresses Star Wars specifically.

Comment: I feel like this question should be reopened and the other should be closed as "too broad".